# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in google map api v2

Tags: android

i was trying to make an application based on google map api v2 and google places,followed a tutorial and my application was working well.now i added a piece of code for using places api and foolowing error shows in log cat

```
    02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.abhishekbietcs.locomap/com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.Mapme}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.Mapme.<init>(Mapme.java:48)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
02-19 22:18:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    ... 11 more
```

the meinfest is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.abhishekbietcs.locomap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.Mapme"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mapme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.Aboutus"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mapme"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ABOUT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.ViewPrefrence"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mapme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEWPREFRENCE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my key" />
</application>
```

the xml of dashboard activity is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Mapme" >

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

here is oncreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("create","0");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapme);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    Log.d("create","1");
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    Log.d("create","2");
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    Log.d("create","3");
}
```

googlemap variable is defined for whole activity,i really can not understand what have gone wrong,eariler this activity was running now it is force closing,pulling my hair please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: from your log, it says NullPointerException at line 48 in Mapme.java, what is in that line ?

Comment: at line 48 it is String type = "&types=" + pfr.getString("type", "food");

Comment: I am also running into this same issue. I cannot instantiate maps for older devices. For newer devices all works fine. Did you ever find a solution to this conflict?